# Why default screen size isn't (0,0) in GridLayout in javax.swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, flowlayout

In `FlowLayout`, default screen size is (0,0) and we have to set it explicitly by:

```
setSize(200,400)
```

But in `GridLayout`, we don't have to call this method, why?

Comment: Probably because it is not on-screen yet, and Java layouts typically ignore 'set size' anyway.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Take a look at the [LayoutManagers tutorial trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). It will give you all the answers you need. And you'll also pick up on good practices.

Comment: Have you abandoned this question?  Are you thinking over the comments?..  A really good time to follow up on it is (checks watch) ..now, when there are so few questions and so many potential helpers.